# Uniquely identify an Android view found by getParent()

Tags: android, view, getelementbyid

What is the best way to traverse nested Android views?

If you've had to find an element by getParent().getParent().getParent().etc. is there a way of finding out whether the LinearLayout I have ended up with is exactly the one I want before continuing with more getParents or findViewById?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can try with `((View)elem.getParent().getParent()).getId()==R.id.parent_id`
if you give an id to the LinearLayout you want to identify.

Comment: does view.setId(View.generateViewId()) give me a reliable unique id to compare to, seeing that R.id.some_id is not unique?

Comment: good point.. it should.. as per developer docs..  [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId()) it says "This value will not collide with ID values generated at build time by aapt for R.id."